# Debug / Release build differences for superclass / subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance

I have an iOS project which builds and executes as expected under debug yet throws a compilation error when being built for release. The error is to do with an iVar which is declared in a superclass and it is specifically

```
'fetchedResultsController_' undeclared (First use in this function).
```

Here is the superclass .h.

```
@interface Super : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
    NSFetchedResultsController* fetchedResultsController_;
    NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController* fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;

@end
```

and the superclass .m

```
@implementation Super

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = fetchedResultsController_;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext_;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Properties

-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController {
    return nil;
}
```

The Subclass interface is defined thus:-

```
@interface Sub : Super <UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    // extra stuff
}
```

In the subclass .m I implement lazy loading for fetchedResultsController

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController_ == nil) { // undeclared error here....
    //stuff
    }
    return fetchedResultsController_;
```

I'm confused mainly because I don't understand why this would comile in Debug but not in Release!

If someone could identify what the issue is I'd appreciate it greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the answer to your question, but it will make the problem go away.

As things stand, in your `Super` class, having the instance variable at all is pointless.  And you should probably set the property `readOnly` so people using it know that setting the fetchedResultController property is not allowed.  As things stand, people have a reasonable expectation that if they set the property, they'll get more something back when they read it.

So, move the instance variable into the subclass.  Declare the property `readOnly` in the superclass and redeclare it `readWrite` in the subclass.

Comment: I took that on-board and after making the changes it did make the problem go away. However I then thought 'what the heck do I need this superclass for?' and just got rid of it from the project!